Обновление значений строк в MySQL при добавлении новой записи в другую таблицу
Только начинаю изучать sql, не судите строго. Не совсем понимаю, каким образом правильно построить запрос введите сюда описание изображения. В данном бд есть три таблицы, сначала мы создаем заказ(ordering), после чего по его идентификатору начинаем добавлять блюда с помощью таблицы ordering_item, как реализовать методы балансовой стоимости(total_cost) при добавлении новые записи в ordering_item Понимаю, что это реализуется через триггеры, но мой вариант не сработал, т.к. выдает ошибку в строке 7, не совсем понимаю, что именно просит исправить.
CREATE TRIGGER update_total_cost
AFTER INSERT ON ordering_item
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE ordering
    SET total_cost = total_cost + (SELECT price FROM item WHERE id = NEW.item_id)
    WHERE id = NEW.ordering_id;
END;


#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около '' на строке 7.

К коду выше вылезает ошибка к строке 7, просит проверить на предмет корректного синтаксиса.
Был вариант с добавлением таблицы объединения, но тут уже ругаются на первой строчке с "WHERE"
CREATE TRIGGER update_total_cost
AFTER INSERT ON ordering_item
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE ordering
    SET total_cost = total_cost + 
    (SELECT price 
     FROM item 
     JOIN ordering_item ON item.ID_item =  ordering_item.ID_item
     JOIN  ordering ON ordering_item.ID_order = ordering.ID_order 
     WHERE ordering_item.ID_item = NEW.ID_item
     )
    WHERE ID_order = NEW.ID_order;
END;


#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около '' на строке 13.

К коду выше вылезает ошибка к строке 13, просит проверить на предмет корректного синтаксиса

Добавьте в вопрос ошибки, которые у вас появляются

@SwaD в основном ошибки синтаксиса, но не могу понять где просчет..
Только их и выводило

Ну так и добавьте эти ошибки под каждым запросом, что бы было понятно, на что именно ругается. Одно из подозрений, что NEW должен быть :NEW

Ну ошибка говорит, что вы забыли про DELIMITER... хотя как по мне, в описанной последовательности действий ещё должно быть "сохранить финальное состояние заказа", и вот там-то и считать суммарную стоимость.

@Akina Точно! Ошибка выходила из-за DELIMITER, а что вы имете ввиду под "сохранить финальное состояние заказа"? Не совсем понимаю что это из себя предсталвяет в sql, да и вроде здесь все и без этого должно сохраняться.

Не совсем понимаю что это из себя предсталвяет в sql В SQL это ничего не представляет. А вот в интерфейсе пользователя это отдельная кнопка. С отдельными кодом и запросами в нём.
